# How to get the closest single row after a specific datetime index using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame I have:

```
            A   B   C 
2012-01-01  1   2   3 
2012-01-05  4   5   6 
2012-01-10  7   8   9 
2012-01-15  10  11  12
```

What I am using now:

```
date_after = dt.datetime( 2012, 1, 7 )
frame.ix[date_after:].ix[0:1]
Out[1]: 
            A  B  C
2012-01-10  7  8  9
```

Is there any better way of doing this?  I do not like that I have to specify .ix[0:1] instead of .ix[0], but if I don't the output changes to a TimeSeries instead of a single row in a DataFrame.  I find it harder to work with a rotated TimeSeries back on top of the original DataFrame.

Without `.ix[0:1]`:

```
frame.ix[date_after:].ix[0]
Out[1]: 
A    7
B    8
C    9
Name: 2012-01-10 00:00:00
```

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You might want to go directly do the index:

```
i = frame.index.searchsorted(date)
frame.ix[frame.index[i]]
```

A touch verbose but you could put it in a function. About as good as you'll get (`O(log n)`)

Comment: @Pablojim: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html?highlight=searchsorted#pandas.Index.searchsorted

Answer (score 39):

Couldn't resist answering this, even though the question was asked, and answered, in 2012, by Wes himself, and again in 2015, by ajsp. Yes, besides 'truncate', you can also use [get_loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) with the option 'backfill' to get the nearest date after the specific date. By the way, if you want to nearest date before the specific date, use 'ffill'. If you just want nearby, use 'nearest'.

```
df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(datetime.datetime(2016,2,2),method='backfill')]
```

Comment: This is the answer I want.  But it looks like "nearest" might return a *previous* row.  "backfill" seems to return the closest after.

Comment: You cheeky monkey.

Comment: This method worked for me except that get_loc is deprecated and replaced by get_indexer. The relevant posting is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75646975/pandas-1-5-3-index-get-indexer-not-working-like-index-get-loc.

Answer (score 8):

Couldn't resist answering this, even though the question was asked, and answered, in 2012, by Wes himself. Yes, just use truncate.

```
df.truncate(before='2012-01-07')
```