# Pandas - Python: Locate a forward looking variable based on time (minutes)

Tags: python, pandas

*Sorry for the poor title, I am not sure how to best describe my issue in one line*

I have a dataframe `df1` with index:

`[2014-01-02 10:00:02.644000, ..., 2014-01-02 15:59:58.630000]
Length: 26761, Freq: None, Timezone: None`

My `df1` column `price` contains some values like `40`,`38`, etc.

My `df1` looks like this:

```
Timestamp                   price1                                                   
2014-01-02 10:00:02.120000  38
2014-01-02 10:00:03.213000  40
2014-01-02 10:00:06.648000  39 
2014-01-02 10:00:02.699320  50
...
```

I have another DataFrame, `df2`

```
Timestamp                   price2                                                   
2014-01-02 10:00:06.879000  39
2014-01-02 10:00:07.457200  41
2014-01-02 10:00:10.625450  35 
2014-01-02 10:00:12.674320  47
...
```

My objective is to create another variable, `price2` in `df1` that locates the value of `price2` 5 minutes after each timestamps in `df1`. For instance, if we look at the first row in `df1`, `price2` will be equal to the value of `price2` at 10:00:07.120000 in `df2`. BUT, I don't have a price `price2` in `df2` at that specified time. I will have to extrapolate... what's the best way to do  this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877391/how-to-get-the-closest-single-row-after-a-specific-datetime-index-using-python-p). This methodology helps me to find the closest match based on time. I couldn't ask for something better!