# Find the closest date to a given date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have an array of datetime objects, and I would like to find which element in the array is the closest to a given date (e.g `datetime.datetime(2014,12,16)`)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249220/getting-the-closest-date-to-a-given-date) post shows how to find the nearest date *which is not before the given date*.  How can I alter this code so that it can return dates that are before a given date?

For example, if the array housed elements `datetime.datetime(2014,12,10)` and `datetime.datetime(2014,12,28)`, the former item should be returned because it is closest to `datetime.datetime(2014,12,16)` in absolute value.

Comment: Maybe you could try sorting the dates then checking the index before and after the date you're looking at and seeing which one is closer to it?

Comment: At the moment, I use `np.argwhere` to find all the elements before and after the given date and take the last of first elements respectively.  The problem is, sometimes there are no dates after December 16 2014 in the array, which is a problem in my script.  It would be much easier to find the closest date.

Comment: You may consider using [truncate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877391/how-to-get-the-closest-single-row-after-a-specific-datetime-index-using-python-p) function.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

This function will return the `datetime` in `items` which is the closest to the date `pivot`.

```
def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

The good part this function works on types other than `datetime` too out of the box, if the type supports comparison, subtraction and `abs`, e.g.: numbers and vector types.

Comment: Wow, neat! Maybe it's kind of what my bigram method tries to reproduce, but way shorter.

Comment: you fail to explain your answer "this will work for numbers too" is no explanation. What is `items` what is `pivot`

Comment: What about a similar function to get the nearest date that is *after* the input date ?

Comment: `min(item for item in items if item > pivot)`

Comment: This code does not return the closest date *before* the given date.

Comment: this is not clear, what are items, what is pivot, and what do you return really? a row? a date?

Comment: This returns a date. The lambda gets the absolute difference between the dates, and the min then returns the date for which the absolute difference is the smallest.

Answer (score 48):

As answered on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877391/how-to-get-the-closest-single-row-after-a-specific-datetime-index-using-python-p) link, 'truncate' function is there for you.

`df.truncate(before='2012-01-07')`

Or you can use [get_loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) with 'nearest', 'backfill' or 'ffill' option.

```
df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(datetime.datetime(2016,2,2),method='nearest')]
```

Comment: I could not edit (too short for an edit, weird!), but there is a small bug: heading zeroes are not allowed as arguments to a datetime.datetime constructor: it results in an 'invalid token' error.

Comment: I tested: the `iloc` method is around 25% faster on my machine (~446µs vs. ~588µs).

Comment: I think using `backfill` instead of `nearest` is more straight forward. Because it literally tells you that it would pick the NEXT index if no exact match.

Comment: This probably should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 9):

This code returns the nearest date **before** the given date:

```
def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min([i for i in items if i <= pivot], key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

Comment: This answer is based on Tamas Hegedus' answer.

Comment: I would change the < operator to a <=

Answer (score 6):

My solution to find the closest index instead of the value

```
def nearest_ind(items, pivot):
    time_diff = np.abs([date - pivot for date in items])
    return time_diff.argmin(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

To find a closest date *and* return the timedelta (difference between two dates) I did the following:

```
def nearest_date(items,pivot):
    nearest=min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
    timedelta = abs(nearest - pivot)
    return nearest, timedelta
```

This may be useful when you have a minimum threshold for nearness for your app like I did.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to answer the slight variant:
"Given a dataframe with a datetime index, how do I determine the last value of column `col` where "last" is defined as the last index that is less than some value `date`

```py
def last(df, date, col):
    return df.loc[                      # access the dataframe using this index
        max(                            # latest date
            df[df.index < date].index   # that precedes `date`
        )
    ][col]                              # access column `col`
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old answer, but I just used the code code that Tamas posted and found that it was taking quite a long time - I optimised it and saw much quicker performance; the problem was the iteration was taking a long time, this is my new method - it will only be quicker when the actual pivot appears in the list

```
def nearest(items, pivot):
    if pivot in items:
    return pivot
else:
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

Hope this helps anyone who came accross this question.

Comment: hi this is useful. how would I write the function if I want to check an entire column in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
def nearestDate(base, dates):
    nearness = { abs(base.timestamp() - date.timestamp()) : date for date in dates }
    return nearness[min(nearness.keys())]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy is about 2X faster than loop/lambda approaches. `all_dates` below is a numpy array of dates.

```
abs_deltas_from_target_date = np.absolute(all_dates - target_date_raw)
index_of_min_delta_from_target_date = np.argmin(abs_deltas_from_target_date)
closest_date = all_dates[index_of_min_delta_from_target_date]
```