# Get value form Pandas DF column that is closest to datetime64

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to isolate a specific `heading` value  where `time` closest matches a datetime64/ timedelta value.

The DF looks like this.

```
   heading     times
0   270.00     2016-01-20 21:39:31
1     0.00     2016-01-20 21:39:30
2   270.00     2016-01-20 21:34:15
3   293.36     2016-01-20 21:29:00
4    90.00     2016-01-20 21:28:59
```

I've created a timedelta, which is `times - 10 mins`. What i'm trying to do is to get the `heading` value for the row that is closest to 10 mins ago and compare it to the current heading value. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Edited to address comment below.**

The ultimate result is to compare the `heading` value to the closest heading value of an arbitrary timedelta (e.g. 10 mins in the past).

So for example comparing the `heading` value in `row 1` with the `heading` value in `row 3` because it is the closest to 10 mins in the past.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32237949/3639023

Comment: Thanks, i've been playing with `np.argwhere` using this syntax `np.argwhere(start`(start = delta object)`<'2016-01-20 23:24:31')` but it returns a list of values like `[[     0][     1][     2]` any thoughts on what might be going wrong or how I use this output?

Comment: `np.where` returns all values where the delta object is less than the time you are comparing against, hence why you get a list. If you only wanted the closest time *before* the time you are comparing against you could do something like: `df.iloc[np.amax(np.where(df.index < '1/2/2015 12:00'))]` Would it be possible to include an example of what you would like to get out of the code? For instance what if a time - 10m is passed that doesn't have a value corresponding to the dataframe?

Comment: Edited the question to hopefully make it more clear what i'm after

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am able to address this question exactly as it is stated. For instance the questions says that the goal is to obtain the value that is *closest* to ten minutes prior (even if there is not a value close to that). I will assume that closest means closest and not within a minute ore some other arbitrary cutoff.

First I would set a `DatetimeIndex` from the `times` column

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.times)
```

Then create your time deltas:

```
time_delta = df.index -  pd.Timedelta(minutes=10)
```

Define a function to get the closest time from the index. This is taken directly from a previous [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237949/3639023)

```
def nearestDate(dates, pivot):
    return min(dates, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

Create a new column where the values are the values from the *closest* time to the ten minutes prior

```
df['heading2'] = [df.loc[nearestDate(df.index, e)]['heading'] for e in time_delta]

df

                        heading   times                 heading2
 2016-01-20 21:39:31    270.0     2016-01-20 21:39:31   293.6
 2016-01-20 21:39:30    0.0       2016-01-20 21:39:30   293.6
 2016-01-20 21:34:15    270.0     2016-01-20 21:34:15   90.0
 2016-01-20 21:29:00    293.6     2016-01-20 21:29:00   90.0
 2016-01-20 21:28:59    90.0      2016-01-20 21:28:59   90.0
```