# Give DataFrame row with date closest to a given date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns, `df`. One of those columns is named `Date` and whose items are `datetime` objects.

Given a date, `datequery`, I want to return the *row* that is closest to that date.

Going off of [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237949/7564988), I thought of using the following code:

```
result = min(df.iterrows(), key=lambda x: abs(x['Date'] - datequery))
```

The way I mentally walk through the code is thusly:

1. I give the `min` function an iterable object that iterates over each row since I want the output of the function to be the row
2. `min` then evaluates the minimum value of the `keyfunction` and outputs the corresponding item from the iterable. So it would output the row (item) corresponding to the lowest value given by the `keyfunction`

Instead of doing this, I'm greeted by the following error:

```
In [21]: min(df.iterrows(), key=lambda x: abs(x['Date'] - datequery))

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

c:/Random/Path/script.py in <module>()
----> 1 min(df.iterrows(), key=lambda x: abs(x['Date'] - datequery))

c:/Random/Path/script.py in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 min(df.iterrows(), key=lambda x: abs(x['Date'] - datequery))

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'm well aware of the fact that tuple indices can't be a string. **So my question is three fold:**

1. What tuple is it talking about? Because there are no tuples being used (unless it's something inside `datetime`)
2. Where is this string coming from. Again, the only string in the workspace is `'Date'`, but that should only be for accessing the 'Date' column, not as indices for a tuple.
3. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer my three questions:

> 1. What tuple is it talking about? Because there are no tuples being used (unless it's something inside `datetime`)

The tuple is the output of `iterrows`. I forgot that iterrows outputs `(index, row)` tuple pairs, not just the row itself.

> 2. Where is this string coming from. Again, the only string in the workspace is `'Date'`, but that should only be for accessing the 'Date' column, not as indices for a tuple.

The string is the 'Date'.

> 3. How do I do this?

```
min(df.iterrows(), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]['Date'] - datequery))
```

So the `[1]` is to access the `row` part of the `(index, row)` tuple pair that results from `iterrows()`. That was the only thing I was missing.