# closest date when looping over array. python

Tags: python

If I have an array of dates like the following:

```
array = [{'date': '09-Jul-2018'}, 
         {'date': '09-Aug-2018'}, 
         {'date': '09-Sep-2018'}]
```

and I have a date like the following `17-Aug-2018`.

can anyone advise the best way to check for the closest date, always in the past?

I have tried the following, but to no avail.

```
closest_date

 for i in range(len(array)):
    if(date > array[i].date and date < array[i + 1].date):
        closest_date = array[i]
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering where your Python code is. This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237862/find-the-closest-date-to-a-given-date

Comment: good shout @N.Arunoprayoch updated the question

Answer (score 2):

My approach first creates a list of datetime objects from your list of dicts, and then simply sorts the dates while comparing with the input date.

```
input_dt = datetime.strptime('17-Aug-2018', '%d-%b-%Y')
sorted(
    map(lambda date: datetime.strptime(date['date'], '%d-%b-%Y'), array),
    key=lambda dt: (input_dt - dt).total_seconds() if dt < input_dt else float("inf"),
)[0].strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

Comment: Please check again of your answer,  It gives me an error `name 'x' is not defined`.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon my bad, i have fixed the typo. please try again

Answer (score 2):

Follows yet another approach:

```
from datetime import datetime

convert = lambda e: datetime.strptime(e, '%d-%b-%Y')

array = [{'date': '09-Jul-2018'}, 
         {'date': '09-Aug-2018'}, 
         {'date': '09-Sep-2018'}]

ref = convert("17-Aug-2018")

transform = ((convert(elem['date']), elem['date']) for elem in array)
_, closest_date = max((elem for elem in transform if (elem[0] - ref).days < 0), key = lambda e: e[0])
print(closest_date)
```

Output is

```
09-Aug-2018
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the dates in your dictionary are timestamps here is a way to do it :

```
from datetime import date

closest_date = min([x['date'] for x in array])
date = date(2018, 8, 17)

for element in array:
    current_date = element['date']
    if  current_date < date and current_date>closest_date:
        closest_date = current_date
# Output : datetime.date(2018, 8, 9)
```

---

If your dates are not in the timestamp format, here is a way to convert them easily :

```
from datetime import datetime

array = [ {'date' : datetime.strptime(s['date'],'%d-%b-%Y')} for s in array]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

array = [{'date': '09-Jul-2018'}, 
         {'date': '09-Aug-2018'}, 
         {'date': '09-Sep-2018'}]

to_check = "17-Aug-2018"
to_check = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_check, "%d-%b-%Y")

closest_dates = []
val = 0
for date in array:
    date_val = datetime.datetime.strptime(date["date"], "%d-%b-%Y")
    if date_val <= to_check:
        closest_dates.append({(to_check - date_val).days: date["date"]})
print(min(closest_dates, key=lambda x: x.items()[0]))
```

**Output:**

```
{8: '09-Aug-2018'}
```

Comment: There is an error  `TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing`

Comment: py3 --> `print(min(closest_dates, key=lambda x: list(x.items())[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use always vectorised operations in NumPy. It is always much faster :D. I would do it this way:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
dates = np.array(list(map(lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["date"], "%d-%b-%Y"), array)))

differences = dates - datetime.datetime.strptime("17-Aug-2018", "%d-%b-%Y")
differences = np.vectorize(lambda d: d.days)(differences) 
differences[differences >= 0] = -9e9

most_recent_date = dates[np.argmax(differences)]
```