# How to get the closest previous date in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, lambda

I have an array of datetime objects, and I would like to find which element in the array is the closest previous a given date (e.g `datetime.datetime(2020,11,1)`)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237862/find-the-closest-date-to-a-given-date) post shows how to find the nearest absolute date. How can I alter this code so that it returns only dates that are before a given date?

For example, if the array housed elements `datetime.datetime(2020,10,10)`, `datetime.datetime(2020,10,25)` and `datetime.datetime(2020,11,2)`, the second item should be returned because it is closest previous date to `datetime.datetime(2020,11,1)`. Is it possible to make something like this with lambda or is it too elaborated for that?

Comment: if you *really*  want a lambda, you can filter: `*_, closest = filter(lambda t: t < target, datelist)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to filter the dates before your target date, and take the max:

```
import datetime

dates = [datetime.datetime(2020,10,10), datetime.datetime(2020,10,25), datetime.datetime(2020,11,2)]

target = datetime.datetime(2020,11,1)

res = max(date for date in dates if date < target)

print(res)
#2020-10-25 00:00:00
```

---

To answer the question in your comment: you can simply extract the dates from your data:

```
data = [{'start': datetime.datetime(2020,10,10)}, {'start': datetime.datetime(2020,10,25)}, {'start': datetime.datetime(2020,11,2)}]

dates = [d['start'] for d in data]
```

and continue the same way, or do it all in one line:

```
import datetime

data = [{'start': datetime.datetime(2020,10,10)}, {'start': datetime.datetime(2020,10,25)}, {'start': datetime.datetime(2020,11,2)}]
target = datetime.datetime(2020,11,1)

res = max(d['start'] for d in data if d['start'] < target)

print(res)
#2020-10-25 00:00:00
```

or, using an assignment expression (for Python >= 3.8) to avoid accessing the dict twice:

```
res = max(date for d in data if (date := d['start']) < target)
```

---

And to address your last comment, if you want to return the dict, you can use the same principle and give `max` a custom key, a function that will return the value associated to `'start'`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = max((d for d in data if d['start'] < target), key=itemgetter('start'))
```

or equivalently, without importing itemgetter, by using a lambda for the key:

```
res = max((d for d in data if d['start'] < target), key=lambda d: d['start'])
```

Comment: Awesome! How would I use `max` if I had a list of dicts, e.g. `[{'start': datetime.datetime(2020,10,10)}, {'start': datetime.datetime(2020,10,25)}, {'start': datetime.datetime(2020,11,2)}]`?

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion – I actually meant in regards to extracting the full dict then, instead of just the date. E.g. to return `{'start': datetime.datetime(2020,10,25)}`

Answer (score 1):

Since `datetime.datetime` objects are can be compared to one another, you can use max:

```
import datetime

dates = (
    datetime.datetime(2020,10,10),
    datetime.datetime(2020,10,25),
    datetime.datetime(2020,11,2)
)

date = datetime.datetime(2020,11,1)

print(max(d for d in dates if d < date))
```

Output:

```
2020-10-25 00:00:00
>>>
```