# Is there a way to get next row value or prior row value when the string match doesnt occur in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am trying to query a date column in pandas dataframe and return price column value - however, if the date isn't matched (say holiday or a weekend date) the next available date column and price value need to be returned...is there a method in pandas or numpy that can help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the closest date to a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237862/find-the-closest-date-to-a-given-date)

Comment: I think it does - but it gets in 2 steps: find the next date and get the column value corresponding to that....I was thinking if we can get it in one hop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one-liner:

```
out = (df.loc[df['date'].sub(pd.to_datetime('2022-07-03'))
                        .loc[lambda x: x.dt.days>=0].head(1).index])
print(out)

# Output
        date  price
2 2022-07-05     30
```

Input dataframe:

```
>>> df
        date  price
0 2022-07-01     10
1 2022-07-02     20
2 2022-07-05     30
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution (to match one or more values), could be to use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

target = ['2022-07-03']

out= (pd.merge_asof(pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(target, name='date_drop')),
                    df, left_on='date_drop', right_on='date', direction='forward')
        .filter(regex='^((?!_drop).)*$')
     )
```

output:

```
        date  price
0 2022-07-05     30
```